# Add macOS Console Application to Accessibility

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, accessibility

I've developed an Accessibility API console application in C++ for High Sierra (and lower) - uses AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue etc.

I've disabled SIP to give me a chance here to write to the Accessibility database using tccutil.

So, the application runs as expected in Xcode, given that I've enabled 'Xcode' in System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Privacy->Accessibility.

I've wrapped my console application into a .app so I can drag and drop into this Accessibility panel.

If I run the application outside of Xcode in a Terminal window, I have to also give Terminal.app Accessibility rights for the application to use the API otherwise nothing is extracted.  This then seems that you must give the calling application the rights.

I'm trying to launch the application on startup via a LaunchAgent with root privileges, /usr/bin/sudo being the calling application.  Launching a script instead to run the application seemed the better method.  The application launches fine, infact the console application inside the .app is also added now to the Accessibility panel.

Unfortunately, the Accessibility side of things is still not working and I've run out of ideas?

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.